# VB.Net Listview Groups

Tags: vb.net, listview, organization, items

I am new here and come up with my first question:
I have a listview with some groups, every groups has some items.
I added a ContextMenuStrip to the Listview, and when I rightclick on the selected item, I like to get the Name of the Group which it belongs to.
Can someone help me how to do this?

```
If LV1.SelectedItems(0).Text = LV1.Groups(0).ToString Then
    MsgBox("Hi")
End If
```

Comment: show the code that you have tried so far so we have a starting point to help.  otherwise it is like you are asking us to write your code for you.

Comment: I tried like this: http://puu.sh/98Txl/3eec32d3ea.png  But this is somewhat crappy, I dont like to create a endless long if / elseif statement, isnt there a better solution like a loop or something?

Comment: all code should be posted here; edit your post.  no one likes to go to youtube or facebook or imgshack to see **code**.  the code does not match your question - you said you wanted to see the group on right click, the code shows selected which is not the same thing.  You do know that the Group will show when `View = Detail`, right?

Comment: This is in the click event of the Contextmenustripitem. Its the relevant part, where the group the selected item belongs to should get identified.

Comment: `LV1.SelectedItems` is not the same as the item the mouse is/was down over; they are 2 different things. what do you want to do with the Group name? just get it into a var?

Comment: The goal is to check if the selected listview item belongs to a group "Test" then do a) else if it belongs to a group "Test2" then do b) etc

Answer (score 1):

Get LV group name for the item the mouse is down over:

```
Private thisGroupName As String = ""

Private Sub MouseDown(sender, e As MouseEventArgs)...
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        thisGroupName = GetLVGroupAt(e.X, e.Y)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetLVGroupAt(X As Integer, Y as Integer) As String
    Dim theGrp As String = ""

    Dim ht As ListViewHitTestInfo = myLV.HitTest(X, Y)
    ' the mouse might be down over a NON item area, like a blank "row"
    ' AND if the items does not belong to a Group, 'Group' will
    ' be Nothing:
    If (ht.Item IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (ht.Item IsNot Nothing) Then
         theGrp = ht.Item.Group.Name
    End If

    Return theGrp
End Function
```

Evaluating the Group name is left for the consuming code.